# How do you encrypt a file with an RSA public key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to encrypt a file stored under %USERPROFILE% with an RSA public key. But unfortunately it doesn't work. With ChatGPT I tried other modifications to my method but his were even worse. Therefore, I'm turning to you, can you repurpose my method so that it can successfully encrypt the file named "password.txt" under %USERPROFILE% with the RSA public key.

This is my variable in which my RSA public key is hardcoded:

```
private static string RSA_PUBLIC_KEY =
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
    "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCBBLxxxt8DmE0I7vc5WWgVHjrW\n" +
    "hHJFVNdBSCkS2Psl6CJoZSI6ogJXufiGvgeqfbrvWvmP8ncX7tAm0lMJYTIoytgO\n" +
    "QLFd7KJKBNVwpKGJzs27+vvcPFeMx/pr+luJZ437sC6+uPQoW7dg6cXuXnPiYDXd\n" +
    "fxWoHcT41eunZ8wLpQIDAQAB\n" +
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

and this is my method:

```
private void EncryptAndSavePassword(string password, string RSA_PUBLIC_KEY)
{
    string encryptedPassword = EncryptWithRSA(password, RSA_PUBLIC_KEY);

    string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(userPath, "password_encrypted.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, encryptedPassword);
}
```

The created "password_encrypted.txt" is created, but it is completely empty. I would be very grateful if someone can help me. Maybe by the way, I've only learned programming for 3 years.

Comment: It is helpful if you post a reproducable example. Whats the Ecrypt method?

Comment: Show the  `EncryptWithRSA`method, that's probably whre the error is.

Answer (score 2):

Without having the complete source code, it isn't completely obvious where the mistake may occur. Currently, the best candidate is probably the method called `EncryptWithRSA()`. Here is one way you could write your method that will encrypt your data using the public RSA key.

```cs
public string EncryptWithRSA(string password, string rsaKey)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportFromPem(rsaKey.ToCharArray());
    // Export only public RSA key parameters (Exponent and Modulus).
    var params = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

    using var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaProvider.ImportParameters(params);
    // When using false, the method will encrypt using PKCS#1 padding.
    var encryptedData = rsaProvider.Encrypt(data, false);

    // Return the encrypted Base64 encoded key.
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
}
```

Also, I would like to note a couple of things regarding the given solution and your approach:

- Don't store your key inside your code. You can, for example, load your RSA key from a key file or a certificate.
- You could also use `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` method instead of `ImportFromPem()`, but keep in mind that this method requires keys in [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) format and your key is in [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) format. Using this method would add an additional overhead of having the conversion from PEM to DER format.
- You are using a key which has a size of 1024-bits. This size isn't sufficient. The current [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) recommendation is at least 2048-bit long keys. From [NIST 800-131A Rev. 2](https://www.nist.gov/publications/transitioning-use-cryptographic-algorithms-and-key-lengths):

  > RSA: The length of the modulus n shall be 2048 bits or more to meet the minimum security-strength requirement of 112 bits for Federal Government use.
- RSA encryption is implemented with an appropriate padding scheme. You can choose between [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) and [PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1).
- In my solution, I've used the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding of the encrypted key as the return value. You don't have to encode your encrypted key, you could just return the string representation of the resulting byte array `encryptedData`, meaning that you can use the following return statement instead: `return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedData);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

var publicKeyStr = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDuPHimIBzZHC4RS51y8NV5Trf9\r\n3hZFH6jATjs43JfvOC4pNuf9Boff+TMlBATgO2XLKXh5WLMZRqEX9ddtzuZVroaV\r\ncrSZ+APKwzi3zAqN5cngNAw1Ff8bJoT3cYnQ6J+y/RzfAd/n8sCswsXgkDocfobI\r\nQNg1TcbrjKObJwBGqwIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";


string password = "mypassowrd";
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
using RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
RSAalg.ImportFromPem(publicKeyStr);

var encryptedData = RSAalg.Encrypt(data, true);
var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

Console.WriteLine(password);
Console.WriteLine(cypherText);
```

Test
[image]